# Windows Phone List box flickering when panning

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, listbox

I'm having some issues with flickering when panning a Panorama app, the lists box starts blinking, as you can see in this video: http://www.screenr.com/Aiy8

XAML Code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="PanoramaApp5.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="Transparent"
shell:SystemTray.Opacity="0">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

        <!--Panorama control-->
        <controls:Panorama FontSize="20" Foreground="White" Loaded="Panorama_Loaded" Title="Envato Stats" Background="{x:Null}">
            <controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>  
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="/PanoramaApp5;component/Images/logo.png"  Margin="14,105,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="logo" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700" Height="70"/>
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="100" Margin="10,50,0,0" />-->
                </DataTemplate>

            </controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="recent sales" Margin="0,-20,0,0">
                <!--Double line list with image placeholder and text wrapping-->
                <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Width="435" Height="Auto">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                <StackPanel Width="auto" MaxWidth="440">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,1,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineThree}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,1,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
</controls:Panorama>

    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And this is the C# code for binding

```
public void LoadRecent(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try // In case the user is blocked by the API
            {
                XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

                // Get the XML nodes
                IEnumerable<XElement> item =
                        from el in document.Descendants("item")
                        select el;
                IEnumerable<XElement> amount =
                        from el in document.Descendants("amount")
                        select el;
                IEnumerable<XElement> rate =
                        from el in document.Descendants("rate")
                        select el;
                IEnumerable<XElement> soldAt =
                        from el in document.Descendants("sold-at")
                        select el;

                int i = 0;

                foreach (XElement el in document.Descendants("amount"))
                {
                    DateTime mydate = DateTime.ParseExact(soldAt.ElementAt<XElement>(i).Value, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = item.ElementAt<XElement>(i).Value, LineTwo = "Amount: $" + amount.ElementAt<XElement>(i).Value + string.Format(" at the rate {0:P0}", float.Parse(rate.ElementAt<XElement>(i).Value)), LineThree = soldAt.ElementAt<XElement>(i).Value });
                    i++;
                }
            }
            catch { }
            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        }
```

**Update**: it seems that if the Application Bar Mode is set to "Minimized" the flickering issues dissapear, if I set it to "Default" Mode the flickering starts again, anyone got any clues why is this behave like that? And if it's possible to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: It seems that the Opacity was the guilty one, instead of making it solid, I have set the opacity to .99 and works without any issues.